# Running R code from current remote server in another remote server

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

I have Rstudio installed in two remote servers say server A and server B. Server B has access to enterprise data.

Server A is my primary server with more features but I can not access enterprise data from server A. How do I run(lets say code to pull some data and export it in csv) an Rcode in server B from Rstudio in Server A?

Answer (score 0):

Few questions regarding the network these servers operates:

- Since server B hosts actual enterprise data, does this server allow any connection in/out? or is completely locked down?
- Do you want to pull the data from server B to server A and process the data in server A? Or you want to run some remote code on server B that process the extracted data?

Comment: 1) I believe enterprise data on Server B is  locked down. I can not pull enterprise data from server B using server A 2) I want to pull the csv from server B to server A and process the data in server A.

Comment: if server b is completely isolated, with no connection to server A, then you can't do anything about it.